# Who is trying to be Clark Kent/Superman at the end of "Reign of the Supermen"?

Tags: dc-animated-movie-universe, reign-of-the-supermen

In the ending of the movie [*Reign of the Supermen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reign_of_the_Supermen_(film)) (2019) we see Clark Kent and Lois Lane together in a coffee shop and at the same time.  We can also see the **live TV stream** with Clark Kent and Superman. I am wondering,

1. who is the person dressed as Clark Kent in a coffee shop
2. who is the person dressed as Clark Kent on live TV
3. who is the person dressed as Superman on live TV

The reason I am asking is Clark Kent/Superman cannot be in both the coffee shop and the live TV stream at the same time.

[image: live broadcast on TV in a bar]
[image: live broadcast, close-up]

Comment: and just who in the hell does that bartender think he is?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I don't understand. Are you trying to be sarcastic?

Comment: -iCal.  Sarcastical.  It's a thing.

Comment: The barman thinks he's Bibbo Bibbowski I suspect...he owns the bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It's the Martian Manhunter playing Superman

his powers include shapeshifting.

> The Martian Manhunter has vast shapeshifting abilities that stem from complete control of his sub-molecular structure. He is able to take on any shape he pleases, often taking the human disguise of Detective John Jones.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_Manhunter#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>

Anyway, it's a **recording**, not a live stream so Clark is himself....and Clark specifically tells Lois in the bar.

> "Martian Manhunter sounds nothing like me".